# Get filename while downloading it

Tags: c#, download

We are providing files that are saved in our database and the only way to retrieve them is by going by their `id` as in:

`www.AwesomeURL.com/AwesomeSite.aspx?requestedFileId=23`

Everything is working file as I am using the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

There's only one issue that I am facing:

How can I get the **real** filename?

My code looks like this atm:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();

string url = "www.AwesomeURL.com/AwesomeSite.aspx?requestedFileId=23";

client.DownloadFile(url, "IDontKnowHowToGetTheRealFileNameHere.txt");
```

All I know is the *id*.

This does not happen when I try accessing `url` from the browser where it get's the proper name => ***DownloadedFile.xls***.

What's the proper way to get the correct response?

Comment: Have you found the solution? If none of the answers here helped you and you found it, please share it with us. :)

Comment: I actually didn't find any solution yet.. stashed the code and still waiting for some random inspiration ;)

Comment: So what happens when you try the code suggested in my answer? You never commented in there..

Comment: How could I get the encoding of filename? If I use HttpWebResponse I can use StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, and I found this class: **System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition**.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()){
    client.OpenRead(url);

    string header_contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
    string filename = new ContentDisposition(header_contentDisposition).FileName;

    ...do stuff...
}
```

The class documentation suggests it's intended for email attachments, but it works fine on the server I used to test, and it's really nice to avoid the parsing.

Comment: How can I get the encoding of filename? If I use HttpWebResponse I can use StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

Comment: @NimeCloud I'm pretty sure WebClient tries to read the header and set the encoding automatically. If it's not in the header or is corrupt, you should be able to set it ahead of time with WebClient.Encoding.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the full code required, assuming the server has applied content-disposition header:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    using (Stream rawStream = client.OpenRead(url))
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition))
        {
            string lookFor = "filename=";
            int index = contentDisposition.IndexOf(lookFor, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (index >= 0)
                fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length);
        }
        if (fileName.Length > 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rawStream))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(fileName), reader.ReadToEnd());
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        rawStream.Close();
    }
}
```

If the server did not set up this header, try debugging and see what ResponseHeaders you do have, one of them will probably contain the name you desire. If the browser show the name, it must come from **somewhere**.. :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you forgot to remove the surrounding quotes from the file name. i.e. `"file.txt"` instead of `file.txt`.

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't be wrapped with quotes, but removing them is as easy as `fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length).Replace("\"", "");` :)

Comment: Maybe it was just the server I used. Another note - this works only for text files, at most cases I guess it's better to write bytes rather than text. You can just replace the `StreamReader` with a `MemoryStream`, and then use `rawStream.CopyTo(memStream)` and `File.WriteAllBytes(path, memStream.ToArray())` (.NET 4 only).

Comment: I am new to this part of C#. So, I want to know if there is a way to get the file name without knowing the header which contains the filename? I may be using random sites!

Comment: @WritwickDas this is the standard, doesn't matter what site is hosting the file.

Comment: @Shadow In some of the vBullettin forums, the file names are not in the URLs or in Content-Disposition header! That's why I asked you about this! Later I noticed that even IDM was unable to download from it! [But GChrome downloaded it without any problem] But generally most times I saw that the either the URL contains the filename or the Content-Dispostion contains it! Thanks and +1!

Comment: @WritwickDas I see.. guess you can debug such files and search for other headers using some sniffer or even Chrome developer tools.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, I will try the Chrome Developer tools!

In .NET 4 [Dont know about others], one can Use the `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition` by instancing from the string returned by `client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"]`[I had been using `WebResponse` so i used `Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"]` the name of the file is contained in the `FileName` property and we can also check if the `Content-Disposition` is `Inline` or not, which will determine that should we use the Url or the `Content-Disposition` to get the Filename.

Comment: You don't have to manually parse the Content-Disposition header, .NET has a class to do this (`System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition`)

Comment: @DanielLoNigro cheers, wasn't aware of that. Will try to simplify my code then soon when having some time.

Answer (score 10):

You need to look at the `content-disposition` header, via:

```
string disposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
```

a typical example would be:

```
"attachment; filename=IDontKnowHowToGetTheRealFileNameHere.txt"
```

Comment: I don't think he is worrying about the server-side.

Comment: @Daniel - who said anything about the server? The *client* is responsible for *reading* this header...

Comment: Thanks for adding that - I didn't see that the `WebClient` had access to the response headers.

Comment: Interesting, I am getting the content-disposition after the download and the code throws a NullReferenceException | Is there any other place this could be placed?

Comment: @Shaharyar - run it through Fiddler. If it doesn't *send* that header, then frankly you are just going to have to make up a name.

Comment: Shoot, I just ran it though FireBug - No response at **ALL**.

Answer (score 4):

I achieve this with the code of wst.

Here is the full code to download the url file in c:\temp folder

```
public static void DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.OpenRead(url);

            string header_contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
            string filename = new ContentDisposition(header_contentDisposition).FileName;


            //Start the download and copy the file to the destinationFolder
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\temp\" + filename);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTTP [`content-disposition`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) header to suggest filenames for the content you are providing:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=downloadedfile.xls;
```

So, in your `AwesomeSite.aspx` script, you would set the `content-disposition` header. In your `WebClient` class you would retrieve that header to save the file as suggested by your `AwesomeSite` site.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution proposed by Shadow Wizard works well for text files, I needed to support downloading binary files, such as pictures and executables, in my application.

Here is a small extension to `WebClient` that does the trick. Download is asynchronous. Also default value for file name is required, because we don't really know if the server would send all the right headers.

```
static class WebClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> DownloadFileToDirectory(this WebClient client, string address, string directory, string defaultFileName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Downloads directory must exist");

        string filePath = null;

        using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(address))
        {
            var fileName = TryGetFileNameFromHeaders(client);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                fileName = defaultFileName;

            filePath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
            await WriteStreamToFile(stream, filePath);
        }

        return filePath;
    }

    private static string TryGetFileNameFromHeaders(WebClient client)
    {
        // content-disposition might contain the suggested file name, typically same as origiinal name on the server
        // Originally content-disposition is for email attachments, but web servers also use it.
        string contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentDisposition) ?
            null :
            new ContentDisposition(contentDisposition).FileName;
    }

    private static async Task WriteStreamToFile(Stream stream, string filePath)
    {
        // Code below will throw generously, e. g. when we don't have write access, or run out of disk space
        using (var outStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
                // Could use async variant here as well. Probably helpful when downloading to a slow network share or tape. Not my use case.
                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my turn.

I had a few things in mind when I tried to "download the file":

1. Use **only** [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0). I had a couple of extension methods over it, and it wasn't desirable to create other extensions for [`WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0).
2. It was mandatory for me also to get a File name.
3. I had to write the result to [`MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-7.0) but **not** [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0).

---

### Solution

So, for me, it turned out to be this code:

```cs
// assuming that httpClient created already (including the Authentication cumbersome)
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(absoluteURL);  // call the external API

// reading file name from HTTP headers
var fileName = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileNameStar; // also available to read from ".FileName"

// reading file as a byte array
var fileBiteArr = await response.Content
                        .ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
                        .ConfigureAwait(false); 

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBiteArr); // memory streamed file
```

---

### Test

To test that the [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-7.0) contains what we have, we can check it by converting it to file:

```cs
// getting the "Downloads" folder location, can be anything else
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string downloadPath = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads\\"); 

using (FileStream file =
                 new FileStream(
                     $"{downloadPath}/file.pdf", 
                     FileMode.Create, 
                     FileAccess.Write))
{
     byte[] bytes = new byte[memoryStream .Length];
     memoryStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);

     file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     memoryStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
   using (var result = await client.GetAsync(downloadUrl))
       if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        if (result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
        {
          fileName = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName).Replace("\"", "");
        }
        ...
```