# how do i extract a file name from encoded/rewrite url in C#

Tags: c#

how do i extract a file name from encoded/rewrite url in C# like 
http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-8.0b5&os=win&lang=en-US

```
Uri uri = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
```

above code is returning the blank value.

Comment: What in Dijkstra's name are you trying to do???

Comment: @NikoDrašković if you click the above link, it will prompt you to save `Firefox Setup 8.0b5.exe`. The poster is asking how do you get that file name via C#.

Comment: Is that the url you are using which returns empty? If not, then can you give an example of something that is returning empty. It seems your problem is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4096929/462285 it maybe of some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question has been clarified, try this as an answer.

```
string url = "http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-8.0b5&os=win&lang=en-US";
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
var res = req.GetResponse();
var fileUri = res.ResponseUri;
```

Returns fileUri similar to:

```
http://pv-mirror02.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/8.0b5/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%208.0b5.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally put it into a web browser control, wait for it to load and when its ready I grab the url from the web browser control.

If I understood you correctly.

Comment: Create a web browser control (from the toolbox)

`webbrowser1.url = new url ( "your url here");

public WebBrowser1onDocumentLoad(....){

if (webbrowser1.readyState == ready){

string myurl = webbrowser1.url;

}

}`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how useful this output is, but:

```
string url = "http://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-8.0b5&os=win&lang=en-US";
string name = Path.GetFileName(url);
```

Returns

```
"?product=firefox-8.0b5&os=win&lang=en-US"
```

Comment: If you click the above link the save dialog prompts you to save `Firefox Setup 8.0b5.exe` The poster is asking how do you get that file name.

Comment: Considering the question isn't clear I'm not sure I deserve a downvote. He asked about getting the file name off a Uri.

Comment: And since his original solution was in the direction of parsing the given example Uri, I think what I posted is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: He provided the link in his question to show a example case. He his exact words where `how do i extract a file name from encoded/rewrite url` Your answer does not answer that at all, you just returned the file name off of the end and did nothing to address the fact that the url returns a file name different than what is in the url bar.

Comment: Also to address the second comment, just because he started in the wrong direction does not mean you should push them further in the wrong direction.

Comment: If you had edited this answer to your other answer (which I up-voted btw) I would have gladly changed my down-vote to a up-vote.

Comment: Since my other answer was completely different I wasn't sure if an edit was appropriate. I interpreted his blank value issue in the question to be his problem, so I provided an answer that provided the file name from the Uri rather than blank. I see your point, but I also think my point was reasonable that the question's content was misleading. Thanks for the up-vote on the other answer, btw.