# how to save/download pdf embedded in web page without a pdf filename

Tags: c#, pdf, coldfusion

I'm writing a web scraping program in C#. So far, I have been able to log in to website, save cookie, and return source code of another page. From this source code, I get a link that takes me to a pdf, but the page doesn't end with .pdf extension. In the browser, this page shows the pdf image and there are controls in the browser including a save button.

I believe the pdf page was created with ColdFusion as it has .cfm, CFID and CFTOKEN in the URL.

How do I save this pdf file programmatically?

Two answers have suggested I save the binary stream to pdf. How do I get the binary data in the first place? I have tried the following:

```
        byte[] result;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(billURL);

        using (WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                    } while (count != 0);

                    result = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Do I then want to save *result* as a pdf, or am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: If you don't show how the link/button/whatever exactly is it's not possible to help pyou.

Comment: Because the page is behind a login, I can't really show the direct example. But it's for a utility bill, and after looking at many utility providers' websites, it seems that most of them display their bill PDFs this way. Maybe check your own utility bill online to find an example?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common method in CF for streaming a PDF to the browser is using this method:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=#PDFFileName#">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" reset="true" variable="#toBinary(PDFinMemory)#">
```

Use a C# WebRequest to get the URL of the PDf.  Then check the response header for a 'Content-Type of 'application/pdf'.  If so, save the binary stream to a PDF file on disk.

Comment: How do I get the binary stream in the first place? I'll post what I tried in the original question.

Comment: @BenWalker- Assuming you have the correct url, the .cfm page will *return* a binary stream. Just capture the bytes from the response (like you are doing above) and save the `result` to a file. The file name can be obtained from the [WebResponse headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.headers.aspx). Also, you might check out other SO threads for complete examples, such as this one [get filename while downloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096929/get-filename-while-downloading-it) .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CFID and CFTOKEN are not really needed, (you can test the URL without CFID and CFTOKEN and see if you can still fetches the PDF successfully)

1. Use `WebRequest` to make a GET request to that URL (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023)
2. Save the binary stream as a PDF File.

Comment: When I cut out the CFID and CFTOKEN, it redirects back to the page that includes them.

Answer (score 1):

> I get a link that takes me to a pdf, but the page doesn't end with
>   .pdf extension ..
>   How do I get the binary data in the first place?

In addition to the other suggestions, one small clarification. The file extension does not really matter. What is important is the *content*. A .cfm script can return any [content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type), not just `text/html`. So it can mimic a pdf, image, etcetera. As long as your link returns type `application/pdf` you should get back a binary stream (ie the pdf) you can save to a file. The original file name can be obtained from the [WebResponse headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.headers.aspx).